# Instagram Hashtag Api issue?

Tags: drupal, hashtag, instagram-api

I have used instagram hashtag search api to fetch the results of the entered hashtag in my site.

```
$api = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$hashtag_values[0].'/media/recent?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Its fetching the matched results most of the time. Samething sometimes, its not fetching the results and showing empty ? what could be the issue.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've the same question, I found this api only query the access token's user's photo... i can't find a way to get a list of public shared hashtag photo..